# DataStax Hive Query Performance Issue -

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hive, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have been noticing performance issues with query running on DSE through spark hive.

***Table Schema***

```
CREATE TABLE tests(
    id text,
    user text,
    aname text,
    iname text,
    gentime bigint,
    snapdate bigint,
    action text,
    acount bigint,
    line bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, user), aname, iname, gentime, snapdate, action)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (aname ASC, iname ASC, gentime ASC, snapdate ASC, action ASC)
```

***Query***

```
select * 
from tests 
where (id='a37') and (aname='ABC') and (iname = 'ABC1') and (user is not null) and (gentime = 1520985600000) 
group by user, snapdate
```

***Issue***

```
2018-03-16 05:44:43,404 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 32%, Cumulative CPU 4110.32 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:44,407 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 32%, Cumulative CPU 4110.32 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:45,410 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 32%, Cumulative CPU 4110.32 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:46,412 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 4110.32 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:47,416 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 4110.32 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:48,420 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 4110.32 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:49,426 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 4111.27 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:50,428 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 4111.27 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:51,431 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 4111.27 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:52,434 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 4111.27 sec
2018-03-16 05:44:53,437 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 4111.27 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 0 days 1 hours 8 minutes 31 seconds 270 msec
Ended Job = job_201801161541_0002
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: **Map: 167**  Reduce: 1   **Cumulative CPU: 4111.27 sec**   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 days 1 hours 8 minutes 31 seconds 270 msec
```

To troubleshoot the reason for so many mappers and CPU latency problems, I have started reading about DSE configurations.
So far, I have found about `vnodes` configuration in DSE Cassandra and that could be the potential issue.
I have also verified the value of `num_tokens` in production `cassandra.yaml` file and yes, it is configured.  I don't know the logic behind configuration.

***My Questions:***

- why so many mappers? `Job 0: **Map: 167**`
- why is one executor being overloaded with multiple tasks?
- Do we need to disable vnodes to solve the problem of multiple mappers?
- CassandraSQLContext vs HiveContext. Is there any difference in terms of performance?

Comment: You use hadoop hive not a spark one, base on log. It is really slow and you need to switch off vnodes in that old version.
What version of DSE do you use? to start spark hive use:
    "dse spark-sql" command.